# Retrieve Data From SQL and insert all data back into db using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2014-express

First off, I am VERY NEW to C#. I have been tasked with this project for a business unit at work.

I have a userform to retrieve some data from an SQL DB, and then allow user input into text boxes. Then when they hit submit, I need the received data from the DB and the User to be written into the DB on a new table. It's written in C# and Asp.net.

On page load I have it gathering data from the DB:

HTML Markup:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:contr1 %>" 
SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [Employee Name] FROM Total_Tech_Minutes WHERE 
(Site = 'US.TN.MEMPHIS') ORDER BY [Employee Name]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:contr1 %>" 
SelectCommand="SELECT [Total Minutes] AS Total_Minutes FROM [Total_Tech_Minutes] 
WHERE ([Employee Name] = @Employee_Name)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="Employee_Name" 
PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

That works perfectly. I even see the action on the DB Profiler. 
The problem is when I do the rest of the code. I see nothing on the DB Profiler for the code below.

The following is the html markup for inserting it all back into the db:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:contr1 %>" 

InsertCommand="Insert into OBH([Tech Name],[Total Minutes],[Off Bench Time],
[Submitted By],Comments)

Select [Tech Name]=TechName,[Total Minutes]=@TM,[Off Bench Time]=@OBT,[Submitted By]=@SB,
Comments=@Comments" 
ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:contr1.ProviderName %>" 
CancelSelectOnNullParameter="False" DataSourceMode="DataReader">

<InsertParameters>

            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="TechName" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DataList1" Name="TM" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1" Name="OBT" PropertyName="Text" />
            <asp:FormParameter FormField="Login1.UserName" Name="SB" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox2" Name="Comments" PropertyName="Text" />
        /InsertParameters>
    /asp:SqlDataSource>
```

This is the Button action:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataSource3.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: protected void Button1_Click(object source, EventArgs e) {
  SqlDataSource3.Insert();
}

Comment: The error I am now getting is this (I believe it is from me trying to get the login name):   An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: String[1]: the Size property has an invalid size of 0.

Comment: Check your connection string. Also please read the Exceptions section here. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.insert(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It worked a couple times. I tried to correct where I was getting "Nulls". Then the error started lol. I am Proficient in Labview (2 1/2 years developing). They dropped this on me, and now I am having to learn text based development from scratch. lol

Comment: Don't worry and relax. You will soon be good at it. Just keep trying.

Comment: For Nulls please check your Insert or select parameters.

Comment: I am ex-Army, I don't worry, I just have deadlines lol I hate missing deadlines. Ok so it is working again. I have all fields as inputs, but the Datalist1 and Login1.Username are returning "Null". The datalist1 is pulling from the DB when the Techname is selected. The Login1.Username is just showing the name that is logged in from the login form. I need those 2 pieces of data to go to the DB also, any advice?

Comment: SqlDataSource3.InsertParameters["UserName"].Value= User.Identity.Name; Or use Session Variable  like Session["UserName"] = Page.User.Identity.Name; Then Store it in DB column. Hope that helps

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118831/discussion-between-albert-vincent-and-mmk).

Answer (score 0):

@MMK This works perfectly.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object source, EventArgs e) { SqlDataSource3.Insert(); }
```

– MMK yesterday

Answer (score 0):

just use sql query and hit

insert into table2(val1,val2,val3.val4....) select isnull(a,''),isnull(b,''),isnull(c,''),isnull(d,'')...